# Function object is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was executing query in Oracle Application Express and it was fine. Until I run my application, it gives me error

Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in processing.

> ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PLS-00905: object
>   PURCHASEORDER.ACLSTUDENT_CUSTOM_AUTH is invalid ORA-06550: line 4,
>   column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

and this is my sql

```
create or replace FUNCTION aclstudent_custom_auth (
p_username IN VARCHAR2(50),
p_password IN VARCHAR2(20))
RETURN boolean IS
    valid boolean;
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM students
             WHERE upper(student_userid) = upper(p_username) 
             AND upper(student_last_name) = upper(p_password))
  LOOP
     valid := TRUE;
    RETURN valid;
  END LOOP;
  valid := FALSE;
  RETURN valid;
END;
```

Comment: Your function is in **invalid** state. You are returning twice. Fix the errors and **compile** again. Also, what is the purpose of the loop at all?

Comment: it would help if you show the compile errors for  `PURCHASEORDER.ACLSTUDENT_CUSTOM_AUTH` . You can do that with the following command in SQLPlus or SQL Developer `show errors package body PURCHASEORDER.ACLSTUDENT_CUSTOM_AUTH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Massie says, don't specify length in your arguments. Also, as hinted by Lalit, your use of a return variable as well as two RETURN statements is superfluous. You should either just RETURN the required BOOLEAN value in one of two places *or* set the variable and have one RETURN at the end of the function. I'd go with the first approach as your code will be more concise.

Incidentally, I don't like using loops to check for the existence of one record, but that's by the by.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aclstudent_custom_auth(p_username IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT 1
                FROM students
               WHERE upper(student_userid) = upper(p_username)
                 AND upper(student_last_name) = upper(p_password)) LOOP
      RETURN TRUE;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aclstudent_custom_auth(p_username IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  p_password IN VARCHAR2)


RETURN BOOLEAN IS
   valid BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT 1
                FROM students
               WHERE upper(student_userid) = upper(p_username)
                 AND upper(student_last_name) = upper(p_password)) LOOP
      valid := TRUE;
   END LOOP;
   valid := FALSE;

   RETURN valid;
END;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. Now, it works fine!
Do you think it is possible to use FUNCTION but without parameters? I need the return value.

Comment: Yes, you can use a function without any parameters. As long as your function always returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration of input parameters of the function is without length.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aclstudent_custom_auth (
p_username IN VARCHAR2,
p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN boolean IS
    valid boolean;
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM students
             WHERE upper(student_userid) = upper(p_username)
             AND upper(student_last_name) = upper(p_password))
  LOOP
     valid := TRUE;
    RETURN valid;
  END LOOP;
  valid := FALSE;
  RETURN valid;
END;
```

This must work better.